# Not able to add control of one Thread to the Control of another thread

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, winforms, controls

I know there are many posts regarding this issue but I am not able to solve this.

I am working on a vb.NET Form based application. I am trying to add a control to the Tabcontrol. Control to be added to tabcontrol is in different project. Tabcontrol is Third party(Infragistics) control which is same as .NET Tabcontrol with some extra features.
Below is the code line where I am adding the control to Tabcontrol.

```
fViewerForm.DocumentViewer1.ThumbnailPane.TabControl.Tabs(tnp_PageTab_ID).TabPage.Controls.Add(fViewerForm.DocumentViewer1.ThumbnailPane.TNViewer1.TNImage(0))
```

Control **TnImage(0)** is a userControl and is in some different project.
 I am getting the following error :
*"Controls created on one thread cannot be parented to a control on a different thread."*

After going through several posts I found that **Invoke** method can be used to solve this type of issue. So I modified my code :

```
 fViewerForm.DocumentViewer1.ThumbnailPane.AddControlToTabControl(tnp_PageTab_ID, fViewerForm.DocumentViewer1.ThumbnailPane.TNViewer1.TNImage(0))

 Delegate Sub AddControlToTabControlCallback(ByVal key As String, ByVal tnimage As UeWIImageX.UeWIImage)

  Public Sub AddControlToTabControl(ByVal key As String, ByVal tnimage As UeWIImageX.UeWIImage)

     ' Calling from another thread? -> Use delegate.
    If Me.TabControl1.InvokeRequired Then
         Dim d As New AddControlToTabControlCallback(AddressOf AddControlToTabControl)

      ' Execute delegate in the UI thread, pass args as an array.
        Me.TabControl1.Invoke(d, New Object() {key, tnimage})

    Else ' Same thread.
           Me.TabControl1.Tabs(key).TabPage.Controls.Add(tnimage)

    End If
   End Sub
```

After that also I am getting the same error. If I create same control in **AddControlToTabControl** Method then I am able to add that conrol to the **Tabcontrol**. Below is the code :

```
Public Sub AddControlToTabControl(ByVal key As String, ByVal tnimage As UeWIImageX.UeWIImage)

     ' Calling from another thread? -> Use delegate.
    If Me.TabControl1.InvokeRequired Then
         Dim d As New AddControlToTabControlCallback(AddressOf AddControlToTabControl)

      ' Execute delegate in the UI thread, pass args as an array.
        Me.TabControl1.Invoke(d, New Object() {key, tnimage})

    Else ' Same thread.
         Dim uewimg As New UeWIImageX.UeWIImage  ' creating the same control as tnimage.
             uewimg = tnimage 
           Me.TabControl1.Tabs(key).TabPage.Controls.Add(uewimg) 'able to add this control to the tabcontrol.

    End If
   End Sub
```

How do I use the Invoke method for the **TnImage** Control, So that I can add that to the Tabcontrol. Please Someone help me with this.

Comment: When is the `TnImage` created in the first code block? Looks like it's created on a different thread.

Comment: 'TnImage' is been created in different sub Project. How do i invoke the 'TnImage' in this thread.

Comment: Did you call that sub projects method on a thread? Maybee can you extract the bitmap out of it on the gui-thread? TnImage imageCopy = new TnImage(); imageCopy.Bitmap = originalImage.Bitmap;

Comment: 'TnImage' is a userControl which has a picturebox and a label. I am able to extract the bitmap from the picturebox but I am not able to extract the text from label. I wrote the following code: Dim ueimg as new uewiimagex.uewiimage; uewimg.picturebox.Image = tnimage.picturebox.image; uewimg.label.text = tnimage.label.text. On last line where I am extracting the text, the application gets hang and nothing happnes.